# Will the JavaScript Audio() method play sound if the computer falls asleep?

Tags: javascript, audio, sleep-mode

If a website is running a JavaScript function that will use the Audio() method to play an sound file once every hour the clients computer will eventually fall asleep. Will the Audio() method still play sound through the clients speakers even if the computer has fallen asleep? Thank You all for your time and help!

Comment: this really depends on the hardware, the operating system, and possibly any user settings regarding sleep mode available to the user in the aforementioned combination of hardware and o/s

Comment: My PC is completely silent when it's sleeping, unlike me. I seriously doubt that a browser audio element would make sound.

Answer (score 0):

When a computer goes to sleep it usually turns off all or most resources while saving the state of your programs, so unless you specifically set your operating system to keep playing sounds from your browser while it's asleep, it will not do so.

Answer (score 0):

"Will the Audio() method still play sound through the clients speakers even if the computer has fallen asleep?" **No**